# Condition if string contains only variable and integer Python

Tags: python, regex, string, integer, conditional-statements

So, I'm working on a script in Python 3, and I need something like this

```
control_input=input(prompt_029)
if only string_029 and int in control_input:
    #do something
else:
    #do something else
```

Basically, I am asking for code that would have condition like this:

```
if control_input == "[EXACT_string_here] [ANY_integer_here]"
```

How would the code look like in Python 3?

Comment: Use [regular expressions](http://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to do a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) match. Take a look at the [re module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html).

```
>>> import re
>>> control_input="prompt_029"
>>> if re.match('^prompt_[0-9]+$',control_input):
...     print("Matches Format")
... else:
...     print("Doesn't Match Format")
... 
Matches Format
```

The regular expression `^prompt_[0-9]+$`  matches the following:

```
^        # The start of the string 
prompt_  # The literal string 'prompt_'
[0-9]+   # One or more digit 
$        # The end of the string
```

If the number must contain exactly three digits then you could use `^prompt_[0-9]{3}$` or for a maximum of three then try `^prompt_[0-9]{1,3}$`.

Answer (score 0):

Without regular expression

```
>>> myvar = raw_input("input: ")
input: string 1
>>> myvar
'string 1'
>>> string, integer = myvar.strip().split()
>>> "[EXACT_string_here] [ANY_integer_here]" == "{} {}".format(string, integer)
True
```

Comment: This doesn't really do what the OP asked for - the integer part in the input is variable, not constantly 1, and there's no straightforward way to modify your code to allow for that.